# Saving large numpy arrays using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, data-science, large-data

I have a dataframe with only two columns, one is text and one is with numpy array values, which can  have more than 170000 elements. The problem is how to save this large numpy arrays as files, so I can load them back later. When trying to save as CVS, it just saves it as a short string, loosing the real values:

```
[-8.0152120e-07  2.8887976e-05  3.3898741e-05 ... -1.3205040e-01
 -9.4032057e-02  0.0000000e+00]
```

I thought maybe to save as text one by one, but is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Did you tried using [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)?

Comment: No, I thought that np.save is only for numbers, not for text

Comment: But it works with text as well, so embarrasing that I didn't even try. I read somewher that "if all your data are numbers..." and I stopped there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you can save it as a numpy file using [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). Later you can load it using [np.load](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).